# Php multidimensional search array key and value matching language pair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In php I have two array like this

```
    $array1 = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Arabic
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Assamese
                    [1] => Azerbaijani
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Azerbaijani
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Burmese
                    [1] => Korean
                )

        )        

)

$array2 = 
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => English
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => German
                    [1] => Norwegian
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Azerbaijani
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Burmese
                    [1] => Korean
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Azerbaijani
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Kazakh
                    [1] => Maithili
                    [2] => Uzbek
                )

        )

)
```

I want to search all the values of array1 in array2. So basically what it will do is
it will search array1 source and language pair value in array2. and return those values
which is not in match

For reference you can see in the array1 we have the array block element

```
  [1] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Azerbaijani
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Burmese
                    [1] => Korean
                )

        )
```

which has the same value in array2. But there is no matching for

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Arabic
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Assamese
                    [1] => Azerbaijani
                )

        )
```

in array2 so it should return the error like there is no source and target language for those given pair with source and target language name. So can someone tell me how do this?

The output should show all those array which does not match in array2. So here it should return this array

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Arabic
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Assamese
                    [1] => Azerbaijani
                )

        )
```

**Update**

I have tried array_merge both arrays and after that I have used `array_diff($array1, $merged_array)`
but still its not working.

Comment: @FrayneKonok any sample code for search with key and value pair?

Comment: need to do one by one. no other option from my side.

Comment: show the expected output

Comment: Would help you could give us the array in code form so we could replicate it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest check the updated question. How the result should come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

For some reason `array_udiff` returns different results in PHP5 and PHP7. We can use `foreach` then =)

```php
$diff = [];

foreach ($array1 as $a1) {
  $h1 = md5(json_encode($a1));
  $found = false;

  foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
    if (md5(json_encode($a2)) == $h1) {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!$found) {
    $diff []= $a1;
  }
}
```

**Original answer**

```php
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, function ($a, $b) {
  return md5(json_encode($a)) == md5(json_encode($b)) ? 0 : 1;
});
```

Comment: @NewUser how is it not working? Does it output something different than what you expect or what?

Comment: It is not matching the array value. Can you check and let me know.

Comment: @NewUser, hmm, different output for php5 and php7, indeed

Comment: I am using php5. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was getting all the array from array1 which are not matched against array2. In your answer it is showing all the matching array. You got me what I mean?